# Why was my entry to my SQL Server table committed when I did not call conn.commit()?

Tags: python, sql-server, odbc, pyodbc

I am curious why my data was committed to the server as it is my understanding that when writing rows to SQL Server via `pyodbc` you must first call `connection.commit()` before the data is committed to the server. However when I run the below code without the use of `commit()` the data has still been committed to my table as verified by:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM db.table")
tables = cursor.fetchall()
```

As well as checking the table manually via SSMS.

Here is my code example that I used to update my table and thought that it would not commit data but it did.

```
import pyodbc


row_string = 'FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, MEMBER_EMAIL, SUPERVISOR_NAME, SUPERVISOR_EMAIL, MEMBER_TITLE'
value_string = [['Name', 'LName', 'Name.LName@randome.com', 'Super Name',
                'Super.Name@random.com', 'Some Title']]
ex_value = "insert into DB.TABLE ({}) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)".format(row_string)
print(ex_value)

odbc_driver, server, db = '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}', 'server_address', 'dbname'

# I did try to use this try/except statement provided by Chiheb Nexus below.
# Oddly enough this committed the data but my print statement did not execute.

with pyodbc.connect(driver=odbc_driver, host=server, database=db, trusted_connection='yes') as conn:
    try:
        conn.autocommit = False
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.executemany(ex_value, value_string)
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM db.TABLE")
        tables = cursor.fetchall()

        for row in tables:
            print('Row: {}'.format(row))

    except pyodbc.DatabaseError as err:
        conn.rollback()
    else:
        conn.commit()
    finally:
        conn.autocommit = True

    cursor.close()
```

Data resulting:

```
insert into db.TABLE (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, MEMBER_EMAIL, SUPERVISOR_NAME, SUPERVISOR_EMAIL, MEMBER_TITLE) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Row: (9002, 'Name', 'LName', 'Name.LName@randome.com', 'Super Name', 'Super.Name@random.com', 'Some Title', 'None')
Row: (9001, 'Name1 ', 'LName1', 'Name1.LName1@random.com', 'Super Name', 'Super.Name@random.com', 'Some Title', 'None')
```

Side question if anyone know (not a problem just odd) why is my data being represented in reverse order. I expected my data to be ordered top to bottom as in record 9001 over 9002 and not the other way around as it appears above.

Answer (score 2):

Like what [Pyodbc documentation](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#executemanysql-params-with-fast_executemanyfalse-the-default) say for the case of `executemany` function:

> Also, be careful if autocommit is True. In this scenario, the provided
>   SQL statement will be committed for each and every record in the
>   parameter sequence. So if an error occurs part-way through processing,
>   you will end up with some of the records committed in the database and
>   the rest not, and it may be not be easy to tell which records have
>   been committed. Hence, you may want to consider setting autocommit to
>   False (and explicitly commit() / rollback()) to make sure either all
>   the records are committed to the database or none

So, you need to add `conn.autocommit = False` before `cursor.executemany` and explicitly add `conn.commit()` and `conn.rollback()` otherwise your changes will be commited to your DB.

And here is an example from the doc:

```
try:
    cnxn.autocommit = False
    params = [ ('A', 1), ('B', 2) ]
    cursor.executemany("insert into t(name, id) values (?, ?)", params)
except pyodbc.DatabaseError as err:
    cnxn.rollback()
else:
    cnxn.commit()
finally:
    cnxn.autocommit = True
```

Comment: Ah. I thought the autocommit = True only applied from within SSMS and not from an ODBC connection. I will test this but I am sure its the issue.

Comment: @Mike-SMT keep me updated if there is an issue. Also, there is an example of how you can alter the `autocommit` in the doc.

Comment: I added `conn.autocommit = False` before `cursor.executemany()` and the data still committed.

Comment: @Mike-SMT I see. Did you tried the given example of the doc and explicitly add `commit` and `rollback` ?

Comment: Hum. Why would I have to tell it to rollback if I am telling autocommit = False? That is interesting.

Comment: Well I did use the try/except statement (see my updated question) but still the data was committed.

Comment: Weird ... I think your problem comes from another part in your code.

Comment: @Mike-SMT What pydobc `autocommit` do : [github](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/blob/master/src/cursor.cpp#L2257)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to control transaction by yourself, you need to have both begin transaction and commit/rollback. Otherwise, it is NOT in explicit transaction mode, and SQL server takes each command as one transaction and commit it.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: That was from SQL server's perspective. In python, set autocommit = False will start an explicit tran,which equivalent to BEGIN TRANSACTION.